# When is pectic enzyme effective?

Tags: wine, fruit, pectic-enzyme

I made cranberry wine about 10 weeks ago and did not use pectic enzyme. Is it to late to add it or must it be put in at the start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pectic enzyme is most effective when added before fermentation starts.  Once there are ethanols present the pectic enzyme will still work but will take longer to be effective.